# React Material UI - Tabs - How to disable lazy loading of tabs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, lazy-loading

I am creating some react tabs based off of the example shown here for Material UI: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/.

The problem I am encountering is that my tabs are lazy loading the linegraph components instead of performing all the queries on initial page load. Does anyone have some suggestions of where I can optimize this to make each tab load immediately on page load?

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index} = props;
  return (
    <Typography>
      {value === index && <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>}
    </Typography>
  );
}

class SimpleTabs extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        console.log(props.color)
        this.state = {
            value: 0
          };
    }

    handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        this.setState({value: newValue});
    };

    render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <AppBar position="static">
            <Tabs value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <Tab label="Item One"/>
                <Tab label="Item Two"/>
                <Tab label="Item Three"/>
            </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        <TabPanel value={this.state.value} index={0}>
            <LineGraph className={styles.graphBox} name={"Guest Count"} url={'http://127.0.0.1:5000/***/***'} initialFilterData={this.props.initialFilterData} filterData={this.props.filterData}/>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={this.state.value} index={1}>
            <LineGraph className={styles.graphBox} name={"Total Sales"} url={'http://127.0.0.1:5000/***/***'} initialFilterData={this.props.initialFilterData} filterData={this.props.filterData}/>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={this.state.value} index={2}>
            <LineGraph className={styles.graphBox} name={"Avg Check Size"} url={'http://127.0.0.1:5000/***/***'} initialFilterData={this.props.initialFilterData} filterData={this.props.filterData}/>
        </TabPanel>
    </div>
    )}
}
export default SimpleTabs;
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the `LineGraph` component is coming from, but it might be possible to pass a static dataset to it instead of a `url` in which case you could use a `componentWillMount` method to prefetch all your datasets and pass the static sets to `LineGraph`

Answer (score 1):

Add `hidden={value !== index}` to the `Typography` in `TabPanel` and remove the `value === index &&` condition inside the `Typography` so that the children of all the tab panels are rendered immediately but hidden (except for the currently selected one).

Example:

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Typography
      component="div"
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      {...other}
    >
      <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Any idea why this change would scrunch up the 2nd and 3rd tabs?

Comment: Only guesses since I don't know what the code behind `LineGraph` is. I suspect that on render, `LineGraph` is figuring out some of its sizing. Since it is hidden, it doesn't take up much space; then when you switch tabs and show it, it isn't recalculating to determine more appropriate sizing.